# Using 'performSelector' to return a non-id result

Tags: ios, css-selectors, nsobject, accessor

For debuging purposes, I need to call a CGFloat accessor method from a piece of code that generates a selector from the name of the iVar as per;

```
- (CGFloat) myIVar {
    return myIVar;
}
```

The setter has the form;

```
- (void) setMyIVar: (CGFloat) p_myIVar {
    [self willChangeValueForKey: @"myIVar"];
    myIVar = p_myIVar;
    [self didChangeValueForKey: @"myIVar"];
}
```

So that I can follow the trail of callbacks, I've put a debug section in the 'didChange' part of the 'observeValueForKeyPath...' code and I want to call the getter accessor to print out the result thus;

```
SEL genericGetter = NSSelectorFromString (p_keyPath);  // i.e. '[self myIVar]'
NSLog (@"Key: %@ changed to %3.6f", p_keyPath, [self performSelector: genericGetter]);
```

The problem is that 'perormSelector' returns an id which can't be cast to a CGFloat. Also, Apple's documentation gives 3 examples on performSelector all of which return ids but they don't tell you what to do for non-id results.

Can anyone tell me how to implement the logic I am tring to use please?
Many thanks in advance, VV.

Comment: you can embed it in nsstring then pass nsstring value ....after you have to get floatvalue from nsstring object

Comment: Thank you, Mina Nabil - this might work. I'll give it a shot. If not, I'll just switch on the keyPath enum that I use and call the getters directly from each case. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the wrapping for free using valueForKey:

Again, given this:

```
- (CGFloat) myIVar {
    return myIVar;
}
```

Something like this will work:

```
id *value = [self valueForKey:@"myIVar"];
// if myIVar is a float, then value will be of type NSNumber
// if myIVar were an NSString, then value will be an NSString
```

And if all you are doing is logging this, then you can log 'value' directly. If I'm understanding your need correctly, this should be simpler than what you are doing now.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for this @Firoze Lafeer! It's clear that I still have a long way to go with ObjC! This one's the biz!